# Permission denied: you do not have permission to select from "v_TimeTracking"

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

Permission denied: you do not have permission to select from "v_TimeTracking"

Hi all,

I'm trying to connect to a Quickbooks file from the Custom Reporting side and couldn't find a way of accessing the TimeTracking,Transaction table, (there is no accessible table in the QBReportAdmin Group)

I have tried to assign all the groups to user, but I can't make any ODBC User authorized to get into that group.

I am using QB 2015 Enterprise Trial.

I have attached screenshot of the issue and configuratation.

I did refer , https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/897999-custom-reporting-access-to-the-qbadvancedreportgroup,

But not sure about the solution, not clear what is available what is not.

If only reports are available by this odbc, which are those.

And is there any way i can access timetracking and transaction table.

FYI, I am able to access v_budget table but does not work for

v_class

v_customer

v_timetracking

v_transaction

(Not able to access almost all tables & views )

Refer :  https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/1046054-permission-denied-you-do-not-have-permission-to-select-from-v_timetracking

Answer (score 1):

These other tables are typically not available using the ODBC connection if it's not part of the QBReportAdminGroup. In 2014 and 2015 Intuit added a new 'feature' called Advanced Reporting, which is a separate application that connects and makes a copy of the QB data and allows you to do drag and drop reporting in their Advanced Reporting application. Intuit added a new ODBC user QBAdvancedReportingGroup which does have access to those tables, however we are not able to add that user to the ODBC user list.

I have not found a way around this limitation, and I don't think there will be a way around it until Intuit gives us access to those same tables, though I don't think that will happen.